# Prove that $A\subseteq B$ if and only if $A^{C}\cup B=\mathscr{U}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Prove that $A\subseteq B$ if and only if $A^{C}\cup B=\mathscr{U}$.

I know we have to show that:

- if $A\subseteq B$ then $A^{C}\cup B=\mathscr{U}$
- if $A^{C}\cup B=\mathscr{U}$ then $A\subseteq B$

my question is regarding whether my approach is correct in proving this part: $$\text{"if $A\subseteq B$ then $A^{C}\cup B=\mathscr{U}$"}$$

Proof:

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets such that $A\subseteq B$.

We must show that $A^{C}\cup B\subseteq \mathscr{U}$ follows from $A\subseteq B$ and $\mathscr{U}\subseteq A^{C}\cup B$ also follows from $A\subseteq B$.

$A^{C}\cup B\subseteq \mathscr{U}$ follows from $A\subseteq B$, as by definition of subset, for all $x$, if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$. So by definition of subset and union, if $x\in A^{C}$ or $x\in B$ then $x\in\mathscr{U}$. Since $x\in B$, $A^{C}\cup B\subseteq \mathscr{U}$.

$\mathscr{U}\subseteq A^{C}\cup B$ also follows from $A\subseteq B$, as by definition of subset, for all $x$, if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$. So by definition of subset and union, if $x\in\mathscr{U}$ then $x\in A^{C}$ or $x\in B$. Since $x\in B$, we have $\mathscr{U}\subseteq A^{C}\cup B$.

Comment: As an additional comment to my answer, when reading your proof I get the feeling that you are over attending to the words you chose in your proof.  Don't try to write a proof in a specific way that doesn't flow naturally from you.  A proof is like a story.  You are basically giving steps and explaining to the reader how you understand one step following from the last until you reach the conclusion.  In both of the directions you tried to prove, you gave the definition of $A \subseteq B$ in the beginning of each.  This is unnecessary and should only be stated once in the proof, at the time that

Comment: ...you want to invoke it first.  But I don't see the purpose of invoking the definition in the spots that you did, which leads me to believe you are worrying too much about the structure of your proof.  Let the proof flow naturally from you as though you are explaining to someone (who only understands logic) how each step follows from the last.  The nice thing about math is that everyone has a different way of proof writing.  As long as you are very clear in your proof and don't write unnecessary things, you can write a proof in any way you want.

Comment: @user46944 Thanks! I will consider these comments and hopefully apply them as I progress. I am just starting, and the book I'm using applies this style as it is very introductory.

Comment: @user46944: I let out a loud *"thank you"* after reading that. Been having some trouble lately with overly pedantic people who want me to write proofs that read like military instructions. "Writing a proof is like telling a story". Well said.

Comment: @Ishfaaq Sounds like a pain to deal with.  I'll bet these people are the reason so many beginner students' proofs are constructed so strangely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the $A^{c} \cup B \subseteq U$ direction, I would just argue it this way: since $U$ is the universal set, it contains all sets that we talk about.  $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $U$, so $A^{c} \cup B$ is a subset of $U$.

For the $U \subseteq A^{c} \cup B$ direction, notice that $U = A^{c} \cup A$, right?  Also, we assume $A \subseteq B$.  Then $A^{c} \cup A \subseteq A^{c} \cup B$, right?  Thus, since $U = A^{c} \cup A$, it follows that $U \subseteq A^{c} \cup B$.